# Is it possible to use a custom java class in an android app?

Tags: java, android

I know Android apps are written in Java. I was just wondering if it is possible to use a custom Java class in an Android app. The class uses the following java libraries.:

`import java.awt.*;
 import java.awt.event.*;
 import java.util.*;
 import javax.swing.*;`

If not, what are the equivalent Android libraries I would need for the translation?

Comment: I recommend reading a "getting started with android" tutorial. Android applications are not based on Swing UI technology.

Answer (score 2):

No. awt/swing is not supported on Android device so compilation error occurs. Android comes with its own UI and has its own widgets. Check [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/index.html) for android UI information

There was one library project [awt-android-compat](http://code.google.com/p/awt-android-compat/) which is not active because of too many issues:)

**Update**

[JLS#7.5.2. Type-Import-on-Demand Declarations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.5.2)

```
import java.awt.*; import java.awt.event.*; import java.util.*; 
import javax.swing.*;
```

These all declarations are import on demand. and compiler ignores them if the are not used. As good as in compilation code they do not exist.

Comment: I just did a double check I had the awt as a hold over from my initial development testing. The actual stand alone doesn't need it.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your comment more.

Comment: I commented out the two java.awt libraries to see if they were needed. They weren't. When I first starting working on the idea I was working with a tutorial I found online. I needed the java.awt.event to add the eventlistener I was designing for. When I transfered it full fledge design to its own class I copy & pasted all the imports forgetting which I needed and which the base program was using.

Answer (score 0):

you and use java class. I use [jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) JSON parser. Just put the jar file in /lib folder.
However, I do not think for UI you can use anything like swing. It's better to stick with Android APIs. And Android APIs are actually easier to use than AWT